# GridView with FlowLayout for Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

[image]

How to make a GridView like this in Foursquare app? I mean each GridViewItem in different size with respect to lenght of inner text.

Found the name FlowLayout while searching, which is the name of a third party android library. Making this functionality possible.

I tried DataTemplateSelector but this is not possible by using that. I would need tons of templates according to the lenght of text.

Comment: You don't need to *calculate* the length of the text at all. Inside a `DataTemplate`, just stick a `TextBlock` and an `Image` inside a **horizontal** `StackPanel` and bobs your uncle.

Comment: @Mike I too thought what you suggested. But that doesn't work. The gridview item's width is limited and it is not increasing.

Comment: @MikeEason that doesn't work the way you say. GridView takes the first items width as referance for the rest.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a `WrapPanel` instead?

Answer (score 1):

I did the same design as the foursquare one with a `RichTextBlock` because it handles the wrapping itself and each item can have it's own size.

All the details are up here http://depblog.weblogs.us/2015/02/18/how-to-add-a-tag-list-into-winrt-universal-apps/

Shawn Kendrot did the same but he used a custom control derived from `Panel` with a `MeasureOverride` to set the difference in size.

All those details are up here http://visuallylocated.com/post/2015/02/20/Creating-a-WrapPanel-for-your-Windows-Runtime-apps.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I don't feel comfortable using a RichTextBox. The idea is to use a custom `WrapPanel`.

```
public class WrapPanel : Panel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        // Just take up all of the width
        Size finalSize = new Size { Width = availableSize.Width };
        double x = 0;
        double rowHeight = 0d;
        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            // Tell the child control to determine the size needed
            child.Measure(availableSize);

            x += child.DesiredSize.Width;
            if (x > availableSize.Width)
            {
                // this item will start the next row
                x = child.DesiredSize.Width;

                // adjust the height of the panel
                finalSize.Height += rowHeight;
                rowHeight = child.DesiredSize.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                // Get the tallest item
                rowHeight = Math.Max(child.DesiredSize.Height, rowHeight);
            }
        }

        // Add the final height
        finalSize.Height += rowHeight;
        return finalSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        Rect finalRect = new Rect(0, 0, finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height);

        double rowHeight = 0;
        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            if ((child.DesiredSize.Width + finalRect.X) > finalSize.Width)
            {
                // next row!
                finalRect.X = 0;
                finalRect.Y += rowHeight;
                rowHeight = 0;
            }
            // Place the item
            child.Arrange(new Rect(finalRect.X, finalRect.Y, child.DesiredSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Height));

            // adjust the location for the next items
            finalRect.X += child.DesiredSize.Width;
            rowHeight = Math.Max(child.DesiredSize.Height, rowHeight);
        }
        return finalSize;
    }

}
```

Using the `WrapPanel` you could define a `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="HorizontalItemsPanel">
    <controls:WrapPanel />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Then the `ItemsPanelTemplate` can be used in either a `ListView`, `ItemsControl` or `GridView`.

```
<ListView Name="LocationItemsControl" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource HorizontalItemsPanel}"/>
```

You could reference a step by step tutorial [here](http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone-8-1/ui-windows-phone-8-1/wrap-grid-with-variable-sized-items/).